# ¿Como hacer una alerta flotante para datos que no cumplen los requisitos?

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un formulario donde solicito un email, quiero que mientras uno va escribiendo el email, en la parte de abajo diga email no valido, esto mientras el email no cumpla con las reglas básicas que deben de llevar, quiero algo como se muestra en la imagen.

```
<div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mb-3 required">
    <label>Correo</label>
    <input id="s1_mail" class="form-control" type="email" autocomplete="off"/>
</div>
```

```javascript
function valEmail($s1_mail) {
    re = /^[_a-z0-9-]+(.[_a-z0-9-]+)*@[a-z0-9-]+(.[a-z0-9-]+)*(.[a-z]{2,3})$/
    if (!re.exec(valor)) {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

[image: Algo así]

Comment: Parecen las validaciones nativas de html... Qúe has intentado? Dónde está el [ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Necesitas un tooltip https://atomiks.github.io/tippyjs/